# What is the value of %pi in Scilab?

Tags: pi, scilab

In the [Scilab documentation](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/percentpi.html) %pi is described as:

> %pi returns the floating-point number nearest the value of π.

**But what exactly is that number? Is it processor dependent?**

By using "format()" in the Scilab console you can only show up to 25 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Scilab [article on %eps](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/percenteps.html) indicates, the floating point relative accuracy is not processor dependent: it is 2^(-52), because Scilab uses [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). According to [Exploring Binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/pi-and-e-in-binary/), the double-precision approximation to pi is

```
1.1001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011 x 2^1
```

which is exactly

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

Most of these digits are useless, as the actual decimal expansion of pi begins with

```
3.14159265358979323846...
```

The relative error is about 3.9e-17, within the promised 2^(-52) = 2.2e-16.